# Is there a startBefore() function in Realtime Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I am creating a messaging application where messages are stored like this:
[image: database structure]

When the user goes onto the message, I uses `.orderByKey().limitToLast(16)` to get the 16 bottom-most messages. I am trying to add pagination, and I have the "highest" message key saved. However, when I run `.orderByKey().limitToLast(16).startAfter(key)`, it returns the bottom-most 16 again. Is there function that can get the NEXT 16 last messages?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recall ever needing a `startBefore()` method for pagination. If your use-case is that the user scrolls back from the 16 most recent nodes, I think you may be looking for [`endBefore`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#endbefore) instead.

Comment: Hi. I'm thinking more as in scrolling through messages where the recent messages are at the bottom. So, when the user scrolling past the 16 recent messages, it should get the next 16 starting *before* the n-16th node. My apologies if I'm phrasing it badly but does that make more sense?

Comment: That's `endAt`/`endBefore` as far as I can tell. Those usually go hand-in-hand with `limitToLast`. Give it a try, and let us know if that indeed works for you.

Comment: I think it worked! :). For anyone else, I used `.orderByKey().limitToLast(16).endBefore(LastKey)`. Perhaps this would be a good topic/example case to add to the docs.